# Is every sigma-algebra generated by some random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$. Is there a function $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{A}=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{B(\mathbb{R})})$? ($\mathfrak{B(\mathbb{R})}$ being the Borel field on the real line)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not necessarily. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by a countable class of measurable sets, namely $\mathcal D:=\{(a,b),a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$. By the transfer property,
$$\mathcal A=f^{-1}(\mathcal B(\Bbb R))=f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal D))=\sigma(f^{—1}(\mathcal D)),$$
so $\mathcal A$ is generated by a countable class.

But not every $\mathcal A$ is generated by countable class, consider for example $(\Omega,\mathcal A)=([0,1],2^{[0,1]})$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you indicate an example of a $\sigma$-algebra that cannot be generated by a countable sub-family?

Comment: @Evan: take the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of an uncountable set. More generally, a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set of bounded cardinality has bounded cardinality.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: You mean to say that every countably generated sigma algebra is countable?

Comment: A countably generated sigma-algebra has cardinal at most $\mathfrak c$.  So, for example, the sigma-algebra of Lebesgue-measurable sets is not countably generated, since it has cardinal $2^{\mathfrak c}$.

Comment: @Evan: no, I mean to say that a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set of cardinality at most $S$ itself has cardinality at most $f(S)$ for some function of $S$, not necessarily the identity.

Comment: @GEdgar: How can you tell the cardinality of the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue-measurable sets?

Comment: @EvanAad: The Lebesgue measurable sets contain all the subsets of the Cantor set. Therefore it is at least $2^\frak c$; on the other hand it's a subset of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, so its cardinality cannot extend $2^c$. It follows that the equality ensues.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Nice. Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to add (to complement Davide's answer as well as Qiaochu's and DEdgar's comments) that the cardinality of a countably geberated $\sigma$-algebra is derived in [Folland's "Real Analysis"](http://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Techniques-Applications-Mathematics/dp/0471317160/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1356933965&sr=8-1&keywords=folland+real+analysis), Note 1.2, pp. 40-41.

Comment: Equality **ensues** ... OK.