# Extending Borel Sigma Algebra "a little bit"

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

This is a follow-up of two previous questions discussed:

[Is every sigma-algebra generated by some random variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267584/is-every-sigma-algebra-generated-by-some-random-variable)

[Can every filtration be written as $\mathcal F^X$ for some process $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617819/can-every-filtration-be-written-as-mathcal-fx-for-some-process-x?noredirect=1#comment3298962_1617819)

Consider the standard Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Now, let's pick any non Borel measurable set $A$, and define the augmentation
$$\mathcal F = \sigma (\mathcal B({\mathbb R}), A)$$

Question: Can such a $\sigma$-algebra be induced by a random variable? Or put in another way: Is it possible to find a map $f$ from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, such that
$$\mathcal F = \sigma (f^{-1}(S) | S\in \mathcal B({\mathbb R})\  )$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $f(x):=1_A(x)+\big[{1\over 2}+{1\over\pi}\arctan(x)\big]$?